# MySQL results from one table plus single string of data from another

Tags: mysql

I have a table that lists people and another listing the food that they have eaten. I am looking to run a single query that gives me all people and along side each a string, comma separated, of the food they have eaten:

e.g.

people

```
name    gender  age personID
dave    male    30  1
tom     male    40  2
chloe   female  20  3
```

food

```
food    personID
fish    1
chips   1
salad   1
tomato  2
fish    3
pizza   3
```

And for this to give me:

```
name    gender  age personID    food
dave    male    30  1           fish,chips,salad
tom     male    40  2           tomato
chloe   female  20  3           fish,pizza
```

I am guessing something like:

```
select people.*, (select concat(food,',') from food where food.personID=people.personID) food from people
```

Comment: The above query returns "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be needing a `JOIN` along with MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function whose purpose is exactly your intended result for the comma-separated list, grouped by all the other columns in your `SELECT` list.

Note, I am using a `LEFT JOIN` here, so the person's details are returned regardless of whether he or she has any related records in `food`.

```
SELECT
  name,
  gender,
  age,
  p.personID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(food) AS foods
FROM
  people p 
  LEFT JOIN food f ON p.personId = f.personID
GROUP BY 
  name,
  gender,
  age,
  p.personID
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13aab/3